# How can I override the settings Rails inherits from my environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, passenger

I changed the program in my `.profile` used by `git diff` to one of my own, which breaks the diffs in a Redmine application.

`ssdiff.sh` is a call to `vimdiff -R` which displays the side by side diffs I prefer.

```
# environment variables
GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=$HOME/bin/ssdiff.sh
export GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF
```

This resulted in diffs in the Redmine app not working.

How can I override the environment settings in the Rails application back to the defaults expected by Redmine?

Answer (score 1):

Put anything you only want to affect interactive shells after a block like this (bash syntax):

```
#exit if non-interactive
if [[  ! ( $- =~ "i" ) ]]; then
    return 0
fi
```